# Uncaught ReferenceError: Plotly is not defined

Tags: jupyter-notebook, plotly

I am trying to create plots from jupyter kernel (based on ProcessMetaKernel) and display plots in jupyter notebook.

My Jupyter kernel code is

```
class MyKernel(ProcessMetaKernel):
  def do_execute_direct(self, code, silent=True):
    import plotly
    import plotly.graph_objs as go
    plot_div=plotly.offline.plot({"data": [go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3, 4], y=[4, 3, 2, 1])],"layout": go.Layout(title="hello world")}, auto_open=False, output_type='div',include_plotlyjs=True)
    self.Display(HTML(data=plot_div))
    return code
```

Expected Results: plot displayed in the notebook

Actual Results: plot not displayed, noticed following error message in browser console

Uncaught ReferenceError: Plotly is not defined

```
at <anonymous>:7:21

at m (jquery.min.js:2)

at Re (jquery.min.js:2)

at w.fn.init.append (jquery.min.js:2)

at OutputArea._safe_append (outputarea.js:457)

at OutputArea.append_display_data (outputarea.js:660)

at OutputArea.append_output (outputarea.js:346)

at OutputArea.handle_output (outputarea.js:257)

at output (codecell.js:395)

at Kernel._handle_output_message (kernel.js:1196)
```